# List.indexOf does not exist?

Tags: apex, list, compile-error

I have an error in a method using `List.indexOf`. When running in anonymous window in sandbox, it works. But in production I get the following error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void indexOf(User)

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

[image: Method Error]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method was introduced in the `Spring '18 Release`, which likely hasn't been rolled out to your org yet. You can see the calendar for major releases at https://status.salesforce.com/status. For instance, if you were on `na31`, this release would be rolled out Friday night (Eastern Standard Time).

PS - Make sure you use API Version 42.0 or greater if you want this method to compile. **EDIT** - apparently this assumption is incorrect, and you will be able to make use of this method in any version.

Comment: @AdrianLarson This is being backported to earlier versions. You can use List.indexOf without moving to version 42, but it will only compile in Spring '18 orgs regardless.